# mysql split phone numbers in to recognizable fields

Tags: mysql

I have phone numbers stored in my users table under the column `phone`. They are formatted as one whole string of numbers, no dashes. Like so: 8005550012.

Is there a way to grab the phone number, and split it in to 3 fields, like `area_code`, `prefix`, and `number`?

I tried using something like `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(phone, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS area_code,` and so on but it wasn't pretty and I don't think it's correct at all.

Comment: Are they always formatted that way? No `+18005550012`, `(800)5550012` etc.?

Comment: Yes, always. No international codes.

Comment: Your substring solution is the one to use. You could write 3 functions to do the work for, so that your SQL statement looks a bit more understandable.

Comment: SUBSTRING() should also work: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: When I use it, it just selects the entire phone number. I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MID()` will do it for you like so:

```
create table test (phone varchar(50));
insert into test values ('8005550012');
select 
  mid(phone, 1, 3) as areacode, 
  mid(phone, 4, 3) as prefix, 
  mid(phone, 7, 4) as phonenumber 
from test;

Result:
areacode |  prefix | phonenumber
800      |   555   |     0012
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much.